# Setting up Jenkins and permission issues

Tags: jenkins, osx-lion, continuous-integration

I have set up Jenkins on my Mac lion however I am having my share of issues. I am able to connect and download the SVN file repository however as part of my shell build script, I have to do an SVN update. When I do that, I get permission errors and I can see in output that it is either expecting Sudo or it is having problems accepting the certificate (even though it was able to download the repository earlier just fine)

What are some best practices to achieve this? I have attached below an excerpt of my bash file

Thanks

```
 #!/bin/sh -x 

     # Change to our working directory 
    cd ${WORKSPACE}

    rm -fR profiles
    rm -fR sites

    cp /Users/jinni/Sites/mybuildfile.make ${WORKSPACE}

    #lets now set up the site
    drush make mybuildfile.make

svn update #this causes problems see out put below
```

output:

```
/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000004000001/T/hudson392681277070654613.sh: line 20: drush: command not found
+ svn update
svn: warning: Can't open file '/var/root/.subversion/servers': Permission denied

Error validating server certificate for 'https://secretsite:4443':
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
   fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: secretsite
 - Valid: from Mon, 14 Jun 2010 19:45:39 GMT until Thu, 13 Jun 2013 19:45:39 GMT
 - Issuer: Blah Blah
 - Fingerprint: Fingerprint Blah Blah
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? svn: OPTIONS of 'https://mysvnusername@secretsite:4443/svn/CCN/trunk/drupal': Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted (https://secretsite:4443)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you're connecting to a remote server for the first time, you'll need to accept the fingerprint for the certificate.  An easy way to do this is, as the user that Jenkins is running as, run the command and hit "accept" for the fingerprint.  You can also manage the `.ssh/known_hosts` yourself.